Why do Sync Changes in VSCode lead to rebase when there are no upstream changes?
We have a regular (short-lived feature branches) git flow with one main branch and feature branches going in and out of main. When there are are commits in main not in my feature branch, I merge main into my feature branch (and create a merge commit).
Now, when I click on the "Sync Changes" button in VS Code, it for some reason begins rebase. There are no changes upstream in my feature branch. When I abort the rebase and do git push in terminal, it works. Why do VSCode begin a rebase, and can it be fixed?

You said that in your terminal you "abort the rebase and do a git push". Have you performed the same operation from the terminal? Does pulling from your terminal perform a rebase too? If that's the case, you might have some of these configurations set to true pull.rebase, branch.<name>.rebase or branch.autoSetupRebase. Also, in a standard gitflow, you would rebase your feature branch on top of your develop branch, not merge main into feature.

Thanks for the answer @dani-vta. I have none of these set in my git config. (No changes in main to test on right now).
On the side; we use squash merging of feature branches so no need for us to spend time on rebase. The linked source mention rebase as a personal preference.

The article you're referring to by ThoughBot is about how to modify history as in: "how to do it", "when is it necessary" and "what are the options". It's not about standard gitflow practices recommending squash. Squashing is rarely the answer and it definitely shouldn't be part of a regular workflow. Squashing should be used when the history of a branch is not necessary and we want to see a set of revisions as a single one. Always throwing away the history of changes in favor of a single commit should be an indicator that something is wrong with your workflow.

For standard gitflow practices you might wanna read this Atlassian article https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

@dani-vta There might be a misunderstanding. I wrote git flow and meant branching strategies. "Gitflow" (without space) is one.
Not gonna continue this discussion, but are gonna leave one last philosophical question. Who cares about the commits in a feature branch after it is merged to main?
